# A terminal emulator for CygWin?

Tags: cygwin, terminal-emulator

I have:

- Windows 7
- CygWin
- A development board connected to COM1 port.

I need:

- Connect to its serial port from CygWin.

If I used Linux I would run a program like *picocom* or *minicom*. Also in Windows 7 I could install *HyperTerminal* and open COM1 port or use Putty for that. But I would like to do it from CygWin's mintty because I like its fonts and some other small joys. It seems mintty itself is not able to work with serial ports, so I wonder if there is a program like *picocom* or *minicom* in CygWin's repository.

Comment: Here's a [recent blog](http://www.josephturley.com/minicom-cygwin/) about building minicom for cygwin.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899180/how-can-i-use-com-and-usb-ports-within-cygwin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having done some research on terminal emulators today, I feel the need to hail the virtues of `xterm`. This [FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/vttest/) documents a lot of the bugs in other terminal emulators which aim to be `xterm` or VT-100 compatible. You can also use `vttest` to reveal a lot these issues for yourself. What puts a lot of people off of `xterm` though is the lack of a menu configuration. This leads a lot of people to think `xterm` is not configurable at all, however it is in fact highly configurable, it just has to be done via files like `.Xresources` or command line options.

More gripes include lack of clipboard support and so lack of copy/paste with `Ctrl-Shift-C`/`Ctrl-Shift-V` by default, however this [can be overcome](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588785#145). Another is the lack of tabs, however many advanced Linux users prefer to use `tmux` or GNU `screen` which provide equivalent features.

This leads me to the real answer to your question - `screen` can be used to [connect to serial port](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-apple-osx-bsd-screen-set-baud-rate/) and should work on Cygwin [despite `/dev/ttySX` not showing up with `ls`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918003/com-ports-dont-appear-in-cygwin). With this you should be able to use any terminal emulator you like, be it `xterm` or `mintty`. `xterm` lacks many modern features and so may not be for everyone, but it is work noting that it is difficult to match what happens under the hood.

In case the link dies, here is the syntax for using screen as a serial terminal:

```
screen /dev/ttySX baud_rate,cs8|cs7,ixon|-ixon,ixoff|-ixoff,istrip|-istrip
```

Answer (score 9):

To my great surprise, [picocom](https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom) worked out of the box for what i needed to do - talk to embedded devices. There is no cygwin package for some reason, but building it is as easy as

```
git clone https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom; cd picocom && make
```

Assuming your device shows as COM3 under windows, run with

```
./picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyS2
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe `screen` will do this, cygwin maps COM ports to /dev/stty* devices and screen will take a device to connect.

From `man screen`

> If a tty (character special device) name (e.g. "/dev/ttya") is spec‐
>   ified as the first parameter, then the window is directly  connected
>   to  this  device.   This  window  type  is  similar to "screen cu -l
>   /dev/ttya".  Read and write access is required on the  device  node,
>   an  exclusive  open  is attempted on the node to mark the connection
>   line as busy.  An optional parameter  is  allowed  consisting  of  a
>   comma separated list of flags in the notation used by stty(1):