# Possible to use screen loopback to create virtual 300bps session?

Tags: gnu-screen

I came across [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116310/a-terminal-emulator-for-cygwin/116325#116325) here explaining how to set the bit rate in a screen session. The answer is applicable to serial connections.

It came close to what I needed to do, but not quite. I'm wondering if there's any way at all, using `screen` *or* some other utility, to create a virtual 300bps session that loops back to the current host (i.e. it doesn't use any external devices or connections). Basically something I can launch from the shell that will make all text for the rest of the session stream at a baud rate of 300, as if I were connected to the server using a 300 baud connection.

How can this be done with `screen`, or any other Unix utility?

Also, I have 9 tty listings in `/dev/` - would that limit me to 9 connections maximum?